# How to save rgb frame in speechRecognized event handler?

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to develop a basic photograph capturing application in WPF with Kinect SDK. It looks easy to capture frames in Kinect_ColorFrameReady event handler but what I want to do is to capture frame when the user says "Capture" which is already defined in my Grammar.xml. And then I want to save it with an image extension like bmp,jpeg... What should I do in the commented line in the code below:

```
private void speechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
        recognizedWord = e.Result.Semantics.Value.ToString();

        if (recognizedWord == "Capture")
        {
            // Capture rgb frame?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the `WriteableBitmap` used to display the image stored as a global variable.

```
WriteableBitmap image;

... //write/display bitmap

private void speechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    recognizedWord = e.Result.Semantics.Value.ToString();

    if (recognizedWord == "Capture")
    {
        using (FileStream stream5 = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            JpgBitmapEncoder encoder5 = new JpgBitmapEncoder();
            encoder5.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
            encoder5.Save(stream5);
            stream5.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which part of this code you get image from kinect? Sorry if I'm wrong but I see that you just encoding bits as jpg format.

Comment: @KMetin You write the frame in `AllFramesReady` but also have to initialize the color frame

Comment: This is not the solution I was looking for. I wanted to open a stream to Kinect when I want to capture a frame. Although your solution works fine but I don't think it is the efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @Kmetin I have been thinking about it, and I don't know of another way to do this. It is not any less efficient, as you already have a declared `WriteableBitmap` and are displaying it in another method already, so it is no new code really...

Comment: In more efficient way we would open a stream when "capture" recognized then close the stream instead of using the event handler "Color_FrameReady". Anyway this works and thanks for the solution @Outlaw Lemur.

Comment: @KMetin Ah, hadn't thought of that... Although I don't *think* that is possible with the SDK